# Expected number of uniformly random points in unit square is in convex position.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, convex-geometry, geometric-probability

If $n$ points are uniformly generated in a unit square, following famous [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem).
The probability of them be in [convex position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_position) is ${\displaystyle \left({\binom {2n-2}{n-1}}/n!\right)^{2}}$.

My interest is to find the expected number of points be in convex position, and I am enumerating $i$ points in the convex position and add all the possible $i$s.

Here is what I did, $P(i) =  {\left({\binom {2i-2}{i-1}}/i!\right)^{2}}$, the probability of having $i$ points in convex position.

And the expected number of points be in convex position can be achieved via

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i} * P(i)
$$

And I was using WolframAlpha ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20Binomial%5Bn%2Ci%5D*%28Binomial%5B2i-2%2Ci-1%5D%2Fi%21%29%5E2%20%20i%20from%201%20to%20n)) to get an idea of this number, for some reason the expected number is bigger than n, which is impossible :(

Can someone help me where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You've computed the expected number of subsets of points in convex position. For example, when $n \le 3$ all $2^n-1$ nonempty subsets are in convex position, so the sum equals $2^n-1$.

Let $X$ be the maximum cardinality of all sets in convex position. By union bound on all sets of size $k$ we have:

$$
P(X \ge k) \le \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{k!}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\right)^2
$$

So we get an upper bound on the expectation of $X$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(X) &= \sum_{k=1}^n P(X \ge k) \\
     &\le \sum_{k=1}^n \min\left(1, \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{k!}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\right)^2 \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Getting a lower bound is more complicated, I think this upper bound should be reasonably tight. Why? Most of the sum on the right hand side comes from the terms which equal $1$, the terms less than $1$ decay rapidly. The expected number of sets of size $k$ in convex position equals $\binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{k!}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\right)^2$, so when this quantity is much bigger than 1, it's a reasonable to guess that $X$ will be bigger than $k$ with high probability.

Comment: right, so to compute only the expected number of point in convex position, I should remove ${n \choose i}$ part? which is $\sum_{i=1}^n P(i)$ only ?

Comment: Points aren't in convex position. Sets of points are. So I think what you're probably asking is: what is the expected size of the largest set in convex position? I don't see an easy way to compute it exactly, but heuristically it should be roughly the value of $i$ where $P(i) \binom{n}{i}=1$.

Comment: right, yeah, I was interested in that. what is it as $P(i) {n \choose i} = 1$ ?